# Why is a comment reporting an error?

Tags: java, debugging, compiler-errors

I just did a silly mistake while writing a comment like :

```
// this prints the symbol delta with unicode character \u0394
```

Instead I wrote,

```
//this prints the symbol delta with unicode character : \u00
```

I still wonder why is this comment reporting an "illegal unicode escape" error

After all, this is a comment why should it report an error ?

Comment: Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949130/comment-illegal-unicode-sequences

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20121158/2235132).

Comment: @DiljitPR In Java, unicode escapes need to be well-formed even in comments.  In C, the preprocessor removes the commented code.